# Can't set `currentTime` for videos loaded from localhost

Tags: localhost, html5-video, current-time

So it's 100% same file

I load it from 
`videoEl.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/19evjn1svecnanr/big_buck_bunny_ns.mp4";`
wait for 'canplaythrough' and then with click event

```
videoEl.currentTime = 1.0;
console.log(videoEl.currentTime); // gives 1
```

same scenario but local link:

`videoEl.src = "http://localhost:8000/media/videos/video_test1/big_buck_bunny_ns.mp4";`

```
videoEl.currentTime = 1.0;
console.log(videoEl.currentTime); // gives **0**
```

How? Why? Confused!

Comment: It's seems whenever the host for video and page is the same, the currentTime goes bananas. Because I could get `http://localhost:8000/media/videos/video_test1/big_buck_bunny_ns.mp4` working on codepen.

Comment: Forks on FF, so its some very weird Chrome issue :(